# My guitar has a problem - no signal to the amp. How can I fix it?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, amplifiers, sound

I just started having this problem. I have 2 guitars (a BC Rich Warlock and a Squier Strat), and only one of them (Strat) is working on my amp. Like the title says, I know for a fact that the amp and cable aren't causing this problem, because the Strat works just fine with them. The Warlock, however, doesn't make any sound when I plug it in with the exact same settings on the amp as before.

I believe this might be an internal problem, though, because the volume knob on the guitar has recently become very loose, jiggles a lot, and even falls off sometimes. Also, when turning it, only a few pops of static can be heard through the amp, but not the guitar itself.

Does anyone know what I might have to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Take off the scratch plate, if that's where the pot is situated, or just get at the back of the offending pot. One (or more) of the wires has ripped off the tag on the pot. It needs to be re-soldered. At the same time, tighten the nut holding it to the scratchplate or body.

Comment: If the pot is  'very loose & jiggles a lot' I'd be inclined to think it's been banged, smashed the guts, track is gone, new pot needed.

Comment: Soldering such things is Easy Beginner Level. If the Pot is broken, match the specs before buying a new one: google "measure potentiometer with ohm meter"

Answer (score 2):

Try jiggling the cable while plugged in and turned on.  If you get a signal, the input jack is either loose, or twisted (wires crossing).  I would check that first.  After that, I would do as others recommend and check the wires to the volume pot.  You can probably find some simple tutorials on the web to fix it yourself.  If not, it is probably less than $20 at a guitar shop to fix it (only labor).

Comment: Welcome to Music StackExchange.  Your answer is clear and well written.

Comment: Thanks for for this. Been pulling my hair out trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

BC Rich guitars on several seller websites noted by customers to have poorly-connected wiring.  Check the plug receptacle, or remove the pots and (if necessary) the hums.  Fix suspect connections.

Or have a shop do it.  That will cost money, though...

Comment: All good up to that last paragraph! What a downer man! And irrelevant... I say get to playing, play the crap out of the guitar, so when you get a nicer one, you will sound that much better.

Comment: Good comment blusician, and edit from rock-on. Removing unfounded and irrelevant opinion can be a good call - especially as the answer is now much better.